# how to use while loop to iterate a value in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a path location called "qe/performance" and want to copy "jmx" files to S3 Bucket in AWS. Once file copied, i want to use while loop to list down the converted files(.jtl) in the results folder into s3 bucket. If files are present (successful), it will update the ECS cluster and remove the ec2 instance to decrease the load and send message to the group that file has uploaded.

on the other hand, if converted files are not presented to the results folder into s3 bucket, i want to put "Timeoutthreshold for 10 minutes and use iteration and sleep for 60 seconds to wait for files to be uploaded to s3 bucket. If iteration period crosses the timeoutthreshold, it will send email notification that file hasnt uploaded....

```
#/bin/bash
TimeoutThreshold=10
holder="qe/performance/"
echo $holder
for files in $holder; do
  aws s3 cp $files s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/scripts/ --recursive
  i=0
    while [ true ]; do
      aws s3 ls s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/results/ --recursive |grep .jtl
      if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then \
        sleep 60
        iterator=$i + 1
        if [ iterator -eq "$TimeoutThreshold" ]; then
          aws sns publish --topic-arn ${Subscription} --message "files (HTML Reports/.jtl) failed to load to the s3 bucket: s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/results/";
        else
          sleep 60
        fi
        exit 0
      else [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then \
        aws ecs update-service --cluster $Cluster --service $Service --desired-count $CURRENT_DESIRED_COUNT --region ${AWS::Region}
        echo "publishing SNS Notification for the files that have been uploaded successfully"
        aws sns publish --topic-arn ${Subscription} --message "files (HTML Reports/.jtl) have successfully loaded to the s3 bucket: s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/results/";
        break
      fi
    done
done
```

here is the result after running this command, it still continuing showing the list of files like this and break

Also no email notifications are going thru in either condition

```
qe/performance/

21:49:50
Completed 14.7 KiB/14.7 KiB (86.3 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining upload: qe/performance/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx to s3://retqa-jmeterfiles/scripts/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx

21:49:52
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:52
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-11 17:41:12 1460 results/ContribAccl_Dev.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-06 03:16:32 1653 results/Sample13.jmx.jtl

21:49:54
2019-09-09 15:19:40 163 results/Sample15.jmx.jtl
```

Comment: `while [ true ]; do` should be `while true; do`. But that's not the problem.

Comment: You should start by pasting your script into shellcheck.net, it finds a bunch of problems that you should fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
#/bin/bash
```

That should begin with `#!`, not just `#`.

This is wrong:

```
else [ "$?" -eq "0" ];
```

You don't put a condition after `else`. If you want to do another test, you have to use `elif`.

But there's no need for another condition. This condition is just the opposite of the first condition, so just write `else` and it will execute the code.

```
      if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        sleep 60
        iterator=$i + 1
        if [ iterator -eq "$TimeoutThreshold" ]; then
          aws sns publish --topic-arn ${Subscription} --message "files (HTML Reports/.jtl) failed to load to the s3 bucket: s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/results/";
        else
          sleep 60
        fi
        exit 0
      else
        aws ecs update-service --cluster $Cluster --service $Service --desired-count $CURRENT_DESIRED_COUNT --region ${AWS::Region}
        echo "publishing SNS Notification for the files that have been uploaded successfully"
        aws sns publish --topic-arn ${Subscription} --message "files (HTML Reports/.jtl) have successfully loaded to the s3 bucket: s3://$JMeterFilesBucket/results/";
        break
      fi
```

There's also no need to escape the newline after `then`.

There also doesn't seem to be any point to the `while` loop. If the condition is true it will use `exit` to terminate the script, but if the condition is false it will use `break` to stop the loop. Either way, only the first iteration of the loop runs.

This is not the correct way to increment variable:

```
iterator=$i + 1
```

This tries to execute the statement `+ 1` with the environment variable `iterator` set to `$i`. But `+ 1` is not a valid command. You should write:

```
((iterator = $i + 1))
```

The double parenthese make it an arithmetic expression instead of an ordinary command.

Then you need to put `$` before the `iterator` variable when you test it:

```
if [ "$iterator" -eq "$TimeoutThreshold" ]; then
```

However, `$i` is always `0` because you never increment that. If the loop didn't end immediately, you could use

```
((i++))
```

at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar. It worked. So where would i use ((i++))

Comment: At the bottom of the loop when you want to increment the counter.

Comment: But like I said, your `exit` and `break` statements mean it's not actually looping. I don't really understand what you're trying to do with all those loops.

Comment: i use "exit 0" at the end of the loop

Comment: It's not at the end of the loop, it's in `if [ "$?" -ne "0" ];`. And when `$? == 0` you do `break`. Either way, the loop ends.

Comment: could you please copy/paste the content for my understanding

Comment: I pasted it into my answer, it's the code starting with `if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then`. The `if` block ends with `exit 0`, the `else` block ends with `break`. So they both stop the loop.

Comment: @Barmer I tried running the script based on the input above but i am receiving error ``` /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 13: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: iterator: not found 
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 14: [: Illegal number:  ```

Comment: How are you running the script? It sounds like you're not actually using `bash`.

Comment: we are using aws code build that has defined build stage defined where i put my script

Answer (score 0):

I just want to address the general construct of your if/else statement.  If you get the syntax correct, you would write:

```
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then 
  command_1
elif [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
  command_2   # This can never happen
else
  command_3
fi
```

but that is wrong.  The second list of commands (the portion of the elif) can never happen.  The reason is that if the command that precedes this fails, then `command_1` will be executed and neither of command_2 or command_3.  But if the command that precedes this does not fail, then `[ "$?" -ne "0" ]` will fail, setting `$?` to a non-zero value.  Then `[ "$?" -eq "0" ]` will fail because the command executed by the `if` portion changed the value of `$?`.  Don't write if/else like this.